# Need literature or link to family of cryptographic invertible polynomials which has distribution similar to inverted bell curve

Tags: encryption

Please help me identify a family of polynomials `P(x,k)` with the following properties:

1. $x\in Z_{2^n} $
2. $\forall k, \forall p_k\in P,\ \exists\ p_k^{-1} |\ p_k^{-1}(p_k(x)\equiv x\ mod\ 2^n $
3. Frequency distribution of $y = p_k(x)\ mod\ 2^n$ is an inverted bell curve

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: So why would you name it "cryptographic invertible", not jut "invertible"?

Comment: I need pseudo-randomness on $y$ for any $x$

Comment: How would you measure/define "frequency"? It would be natural to expect just a single "inverse" for any given polynomial.

Comment: In #3, what is the underlying random process? Uniform choice of x and fixed k? Uniform choice of k and fixed x?

Comment: @Mikero, Uniform choice of x for fixed k. $k$ is chosen randomly once to define $p_k(x)$ i.e. $p_K(x)=p(x,k)|_{k=K}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These requirements are impossible. If $p_k$ is a permutation, then the distribution induced by "choose $x$ uniformly in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, output $y=p_k(x)$" is also uniform in  $\mathbb{Z}_n$. It can't follow a normal distribution. For every possible $y$, there is exactly one $x$ that makes it happen, and that $x$ is assigned probability $1/2^n$.